Verification of a proof for a theorem about series
I'm currently reading the text by Apostol and here's one theorem on series:

Here's a definition and a theorem that will use in the proof:


And I have my own proof of this theorem, can anyone point out any mistake? I really appreciate that! Here's the proof:
(i) follows by Theorem 8.35. To prove (ii), let $ t_k = |s_1| + \cdots + |s_k| $. Then by Theorem 8.35
$$
t_k \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_1(n)| + \cdots + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_k(n)| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( |b_1(n)| + \cdots + |b_k(n)| \right)
$$
Which is equal to
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( |a_{f_1(n)}| + \cdots + |a_{f_k(n)}| \right) \quad (1)
$$
Consider the sequence
$$
(c_m)_m := \left(|a_{f_1(1)}|, \dots, |a_{f_k(1)}|,\, |a_{f_1(2)}|, \dots, |a_{f_k(2)}|,\, \dots, |a_{f_1(n)}|, \dots, |a_{f_k(n)}|,\, \dots\right)
$$
Then the series formed by $ \sum_m c_m $ is a subseries of $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k| $. Apply Theorem 8.35:
$$
\sum_m c_m \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|
$$
While the series (1) is really just $ \sum_m c_m $ with inserted parentheses, hence the same sum as $ \sum_m c_m $. Finally,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( |a_{f_1(n)}| + \cdots + |a_{f_k(n)}| \right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|
$$
This proves that $ \sum |s_k| $ has bounded partial sums and hence $ \sum s_k $ converges absolutely.
To find the sum of $ \sum s_k $, we proceed as follows:
Let $ \varepsilon > 0 $ be given and choose $ M $ so that $ n \geq M $ implies both
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k| - \sum_{k=1}^{n} |a_k| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \quad (2)
$$
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k - \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \quad (3)
$$
For each $ j \in \mathbb{Z}^+ $, there exist $ k_j, n_j \in \mathbb{Z}^+ $ such that $ j = f_{k_j}(n_j) $, thus we have
$$
1 = f_{k_1}(n_1),\, 2 = f_{k_2}(n_2),\, \dots,\, M = f_{k_M}(n_M)
$$
We let
$$
K = \max\{ k_1 , \dots,  k_M \}
$$
$$
N = \max\{ n_1 , \dots,  n_M \}
$$
If $ p \geq K $ and $ q \geq N $, we then have
$$
\{1 , \dots , M\} \subseteq \{ f_k(n) \}_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq p \\ 1 \leq n \leq q}} = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{p} \{f_k(1) , \dots, f_k(q) \}
$$
For each $ 1 \leq k \leq p $, we let $ T_k := \max \{f_k(1) , \dots, f_k(q) \} $. Then we get
$$
\{f_k(1) , \dots, f_k(q) \} \subseteq \{1 , \dots , T_k\}
$$
By definition of $ T_k $, if we let $ T := \max \{T_1 , \dots , T_p \} $, we get
$$
\bigcup_{k = 1}^{p} \{f_k(1) , \dots, f_k(q) \} \subseteq \bigcup_{k = 1}^{p} \{1 , \dots , T_k \} \subseteq \{1 , \dots , T\}
$$
Hence we conclude
$$
\{1 , \dots , M\} \subseteq \{ f_k(n) \}_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq p \\ 1 \leq n \leq q}} \subseteq \{1 , \dots , T\}
$$
Since a sequence is just a function from $ \mathbb{Z}^+ $ to $ \mathbb{R} $ or $ \mathbb{C} $:
$$
\{a_1 , \dots , a_M\} \subseteq \{ a_{f_k(n)} \}_{\substack{1 \leq k \leq p \\ 1 \leq n \leq q}} \subseteq \{a_1 , \dots , a_T\}
$$
So if $ n > M $ and $ n > T $:
\begin{align*}
    \left|  \sum_{k=1}^n a_k -  \sum_{k=1}^p \sum_{n=1}^q a_{f_k(n)} \right| &\leq \sum_{k = M+1}^{n} |a_{k}| \\
    &\leq \sum_{k = M+1}^{\infty} |a_{k}| \\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k| - \sum_{k=1}^{M} |a_k| \\
    \text{by (2)} \quad &< \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
\end{align*}
Combine with (3) and use the triangle inequality, we have
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k - \sum_{k=1}^p \sum_{n=1}^q a_{f_k(n)} \right| < \varepsilon \quad \forall p \geq K ,\, \forall q \geq N \quad (4)
$$
Leave $ p \geq K $ fixed, and define $ t_p(q) = \sum_{k=1}^p \sum_{n=1}^q b_k(n) $ for each $ q \geq 1 $. We may define $ s_k(q) =  \sum_{n=1}^q b_k(n) $, so
$$
t_p(q) = \sum_{k=1}^p s_k(q)
$$
As $ s_k(q) \to s_k $ as $ q \to \infty $, by applying the limit rules for sums of sequences, this gives that $ t_p(q) \to \sum_{k=1}^p s_k $ as $ q \to \infty $. Hence, by (4), we have
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k - \sum_{k=1}^p s_k\right| \leq \varepsilon \quad \forall p \geq K
$$
Where $ K $ depends on $ M $, and $ M $ depends on $ \varepsilon $. Thus, the result follows.
